# How to set ListView to Start showing the last Item instead in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list of Items being handled by the ListView. By default, the ListView shows the from start to bottom (scrolling).

How do I set the ListView to start at the bottom instead?

Usage:
Chat Messages View - Wherein I need to show the last message of the chat and scroll to that.

Comment: Have you tried reverting the list order before putting it inside the listview items?

Comment: kindly include your code so we can see how you are implement it.

Comment: Hmmm. With that, I'll still be starting from the top of the scroll just with the first item to be the last item (sorted reverse).

Comment: What I want is to have the ListView to start at the bottom of the list (as well as the scroll)

Comment: @Poody Have you tried actually reading the OP's question before putting in a comment?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `ScrollTo` in a `ListView` to scroll to a any position you set. You need to overwrite the `OnAppearing` method. This is an example for scrolling to the end of the `ListView` ViewModel.Messages:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        ViewModel.RefreshScrollDown = () => {
            if (ViewModel.Messages.Count > 0) {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {

                    ListViewMessages.ScrollTo (ViewModel.Messages [ViewModel.Messages.Count - 1], ScrollToPosition.End, true);
                });
            }
        };
    }
```

Then just call `RefreshScrollDown` (which is `System.Action`) every time you need to scroll down, e.g. when you receive a new message or when you load the chats.

**RefreshScrollDown in ViewModel:**

```
public System.Action RefreshScrollDown;
```

**You can get your ViewModel in code behind like this:**

```
private MessagePhonePageViewModel ViewModel {
    get { return BindingContext as MessagePhonePageViewModel;}
}
```

---

NOTE: There is a bug when using a fixed `ListView` height. When changing the `HeightRequest`, **ScrollTo** still uses the original height of the list to calculate where it scrolls to. The original height is not updated when you change the value in `HeightRequest`. To fix this issue:

```
 protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (e.PropertyName == Xamarin.Forms.ListView.HeightRequestProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                Control.LayoutParameters.Height =(int)(sender as Xamarin.Forms.ListView).HeightRequest;
                Control.RequestLayout();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the tip - my question now is where to put this so that it can be triggered once all the items are loaded on my ListView.

Do I need to override the onAppearing method of the page and add it there?

Comment: It works on IOS but on Android it does not seem to be doing anything. The list is not scrolling after it loads.

Comment: @Raven actually I just got told by my coworker that it works on iOS and Android, so you are most likely right what it doesn't work on Android. In case you find out why it doesn't work, could you tell us why?

Comment: Hmm, @zure, I managed to get it working on Android! My bad, it was not working due to our app flow logic - but the solution above works for the problem that I mentioned. So thanks!

Comment: Cool! Unfortunately I can't get it working on UWP tho!

Comment: Haha that's ok for me, we don't support UWP xD

Comment: Got it working on UWP. The issue was not related to this topic tho.

Comment: There was previously some reports that Android didn't scroll to the end when using ScrollToPosition.End. If that is the case try ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible

Comment: @Visualspark thanks for the hint! `ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible` only worked for me by disabling animated with false -> `listView.ScrollTo(e.Item, ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible, false);`