# Scroll down on Custom ListView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Well as most of all, I´m trying to implement a Chat in a Xamarin Forms app, the chat works like a charm with a little exception, I can´t make it scroll down when adding a new item to the listview, neither can I make it scroll all the way down when it loads the first conversation.

Please keep in mind that I´m taking this for learning purposes.

My code is:

ChatViewModel:

```
public class ChatViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private IChatServices _chatServices;



        #region ViewModel Properties

        private ObservableCollection<ChatMessageViewModel> _messages;

        public ObservableCollection<ChatMessageViewModel> Messages
        {
            get { return _messages; }
            set
            {
                _messages = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Messages");
            }
        }

        private ChatMessageViewModel _chatMessage;
        public ChatMessageViewModel ChatMessage
        {
            get { return _chatMessage; }
            set
            {
                _chatMessage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ChatMessage");
            }
        }


        #endregion

        public ChatViewModel()
        {
            _chatServices = DependencyService.Get<IChatServices>();
            _chatMessage = new ChatMessageViewModel();

            _messages = new ObservableCollection<ChatMessageViewModel>();
            _chatServices.Connect();
            _chatServices.OnMessageReceived += _chatServices_OnMessageReceived;
            StartConversation();
        }

        void _chatServices_OnMessageReceived(object sender, ChatMessage e)
        {
            _messages.Add(new ChatMessageViewModel { Name = e.Name, Message = e.Message, IsMine = _messages.Count % 2 == 0 });


        }



        #region Send Message Command

        Command sendMessageCommand;

        /// <summary>
        /// Command to Send Message
        /// </summary>
        public Command SendMessageCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return sendMessageCommand ??
                (sendMessageCommand = new Command(ExecuteSendMessageCommand));
            }
        }

        async void ExecuteSendMessageCommand()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            await _chatServices.Send(new ChatMessage { Name = Application.Current.Resources["NomeDoUserEmDBLocal"].ToString(), Message = _chatMessage.Message });
            IsBusy = false;
        }

        #endregion

        private async void StartConversation()
        {
            // obter lista do webservice
            Services.ApiServices services = new Services.ApiServices();
            var listWebService = await services.GetLast10Msg(Application.Current.Resources["TokenOATH"].ToString());

            List<ChatMessageViewModel> listaInverter = new List<ChatMessageViewModel>();

            foreach (var item in listWebService)
            {

                ChatMessageViewModel novaVM = new ChatMessageViewModel();
                novaVM.Name = item.Name;
                novaVM.Message = item.Message;
                listaInverter.Add(novaVM);

            }

            for (int i = (listaInverter.Count - 1); i >= 0; i--)
            {
                Messages.Add(listaInverter[i]);

            }


        }
}
```

ChatListView :

```
public class ChatListView : ListView
    {
        public Action<int, int, bool> ScrollToRowDelegate { get; set; }

        public void ScrollToRow(int itemIndex, int sectionIndex , bool animated = false)
        {
            if (ScrollToRowDelegate != null)
            {
                ScrollToRowDelegate(itemIndex, sectionIndex, animated);
            }
        }


    }
```

ChatServices:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ChatServices))]
namespace xxx.Services
{
    public class ChatServices : IChatServices
    {
        private readonly HubConnection _connection;
        private readonly IHubProxy _proxy;

        public event EventHandler<ChatMessage> OnMessageReceived;

        public ChatServices()
        {
            _connection = new HubConnection(App.SignalRUrl);
            _proxy = _connection.CreateHubProxy("xxx");
            _proxy.On("GetMessage", (string name, string message) => OnMessageReceived(this, new ChatMessage
            {
                Name = name,
                Message = message,

            }));
        }

        #region IChatServices implementation

        public async Task Connect()
        {

            var http = new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.DefaultHttpClient();

            await _connection.Start(new WebSocketTransportLayer(http));
        }

        public async Task Send(ChatMessage message)
        {
            if (_connection.State == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
            {
                await Connect();
            }
            await _proxy.Invoke("SendMessage", Application.Current.Resources["xxxNomexxx"].ToString(), message.Message);
        }



        #endregion
    }
```

MessageRenderer :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MessageViewCell), typeof(MessageRenderer))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
    public class MessageRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context context)
        {
            var inflatorservice = (LayoutInflater)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            var dataContext = item.BindingContext as ChatMessageViewModel;



            var textMsgVm = dataContext as ChatMessageViewModel;
            if (textMsgVm != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textMsgVm.Image))
                {
                    var template = (LinearLayout)inflatorservice.Inflate(textMsgVm.IsMine ? Resource.Layout.image_item_owner : Resource.Layout.image_item_opponent, null, false);

                    template.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nick).Text = textMsgVm.IsMine ? "Eu:" : textMsgVm.Name + ":";
                    template.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.image).SetImageBitmap(GetImageBitmapFromUrl(textMsgVm.Image));
                    Android.Widget.ListView thisCellsListView = (Android.Widget.ListView)parent;

                    //This CustomListView is a Xamarin.Forms.ListView that has a Custom ListView Renderer in my IOS version
                    ChatListView tableParent = (ChatListView)base.ParentView;

                    //Wire the Delegate on the first cell creation, just once, and pass Android's ListView Instance

                    tableParent.ScrollToRowDelegate = (itemIndex, sectionIndex, animated) =>
                    {
                        ScrollToRow(thisCellsListView, itemIndex, sectionIndex, animated);

                    };
                    return template;
                }
                else
                {
                    var template = (LinearLayout)inflatorservice.Inflate(textMsgVm.IsMine ? Resource.Layout.message_item_owner : Resource.Layout.message_item_opponent, null, false);

                    template.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nick).Text = textMsgVm.IsMine ? "Eu:" : textMsgVm.Name + ":";
                    template.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.message).Text = textMsgVm.Message;
                    Android.Widget.ListView thisCellsListView = (Android.Widget.ListView)parent;

                    //This CustomListView is a Xamarin.Forms.ListView that has a Custom ListView Renderer in my IOS version
                    ChatListView tableParent = (ChatListView)base.ParentView;

                    //Wire the Delegate on the first cell creation, just once, and pass Android's ListView Instance

                    tableParent.ScrollToRowDelegate = (itemIndex, sectionIndex, animated) =>
                    {
                        ScrollToRow(thisCellsListView, itemIndex, sectionIndex, animated);

                    };
                    return template;
                }
            }



            return base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context);
        }

        private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
        {
            Bitmap imageBitmap = null;
            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
                if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
                {
                    imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                }
            }
            return imageBitmap;
        }


        protected override void OnCellPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnCellPropertyChanged(sender, e);


        }

        private void ScrollToRow(ViewGroup parent, int itemIndex, int sectionIndex, bool animated)
        {
            //Get Android's ListView 
            Android.Widget.ListView thisCellsListView = (Android.Widget.ListView)parent;

            thisCellsListView.SetSelection(itemIndex);
        }



    }
```

If anyone has any ideia where and how to make this scroll auto to the new message received, please pin point even if it´s documentation. The scrollto method is not working or I´m implementing it poorly.

Best regards

Comment: I used scrollTo before and it was working fine. What behavior are you getting from it right now? Make sure that you are passing all the correct values and that you have a reference to the list

Comment: I am surelly messing it up. At first I tried when the onmessagereceiveid event fires to call customlistview.scrollto(newCreatedMessage, scrolltoEnum.makevisible, false ) something like this (writing this comment from memory as I´m not in front of the code right now) maybe I´m messing up the event or the message....

Comment: try a simple step. Add a simple list and give it x:name, from the code behind , try to control it by calling the scroll to function.

It will be much easier than working with Viewmodels.
After that , move the logic to the VM

Comment: I would try making a renderer on Android for your `ChatListView` and try setting `listView.TranscriptMode = TranscriptMode.AlwaysScroll;` and  `listView.StackFromBottom = true;`, which should handle scrolling to the bottom for you.

Comment: Will look into it Nick and as soon as I try I´ll provide feedback here. Also Ali123 will consider implementing a small step as you say. Will provide feedback as soon as attempeted the replies

Comment: Thanks both! Nick your solution worked very well, created the list view in a rendered Android, and set those and it work! Ali123 your coment made me see how it worked without the viewmodel and I could then extrapolate to the VM! Now how can I mark the comments as an answer to my question LOL ???

Comment: [This is another way to achieve scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373761/how-to-set-listview-to-start-showing-the-last-item-instead-in-xamarin-forms/40374686#40374686)

Comment: Thank you Dennis for the insight! Although I have this issue already solved, I will try it out also the approach you brought tonight as this is for learning path and I want to consider all the ways I have! Again thanks!