# Automatically scroll down ListView in Xamarin

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I have `ListView` with binding `ItemsSource` (it is `ObservableRangeCollection`). I want to automatically scroll down `ListView` when page is appearing. What should I do?
It is `View`:

```
<ListView 
        x:Name="ListAdd"            
        ItemsSource="{Binding AddNewFlashcard}"
        (...)
            >
            <ListView.Behaviors>
                <(...)>
            </ListView.Behaviors>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Flashcard">
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Frame CornerRadius="20" HasShadow="True">
                                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
                                    <Label FontSize="Large"
                                        Text="{Binding Word}"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Sentence}"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

It is ViewModel:

```
public ObservableRangeCollection<Flashcard> AddNewFlashcard { get; set; }

        public NewFlashcardVM()
        {            
            Refresh();
            AddNewFlashcard = new ObservableRangeCollection<Flashcard>(); 
        }



        public async void Refresh() 
        {
            IsBusy = true;      
            var flashcards = await FlashcardService.GetFlashcard();
            AddNewFlashcard.AddRange(flashcards);
            IsBusy = false;
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set ListView to Start showing the last Item instead in Xamarin Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373761/how-to-set-listview-to-start-showing-the-last-item-instead-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. Maybe I should  try one again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the effect you want by calling the **ScrollTo** method in the ListView.

I wrote a small example for your reference.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Frame HeightRequest="100">
        <ListView x:Name="mytest" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Label Text="{Binding .}"></Label>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

Here is the background code(When the data is loaded, call the ScrollTo method of ListView in the OnAppearing method):

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    ObservableRangeCollection<string> myList;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myList = new ObservableRangeCollection<string>();
        myList.Add("aaa");
        myList.Add("aaa");
        myList.Add("aaa");
        myList.Add("aaa");
        myList.Add("aaa");
        myList.Add("aaa"); 
        myList.Add("bbb");
        mytest.ItemsSource = myList;
        BindingContext = this;
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        mytest.ScrollTo(myList[myList.Count-1], ScrollToPosition.End,false);
    }
}
```

If you change the last parameter of **ScrollTo** to **true**, a **sliding animation** will occur.

Comment: In OnAppearing I have this code: 
`protected override void OnAppearing()
        {           
            base.OnAppearing();
            ListAdd.ScrollTo(NewFlashcardVM.AddNewFlashcard[NewFlashcardVM.AddNewFlashcard.Count - 1], ScrollToPosition.End, false);
        }`
I put breakpoint there and I see that **NewFlashcardVM.AddNewFlashcard.Count** equals 0. But when I wrote this code in xaml: 

 `<Label Text="{Binding AddNewFlashcard.Count}"/>`

it returns me **32**.  I don't know what I should to do now. Maybe have you any idea?

Comment: Make sure there are values in the array, which is equivalent to ObservableRangeCollection.Count.

Comment: What do you mean? Without change in **OnAppearing** everything is appearing. I am new in coding, so sorry for my question :).

Comment: What is the name of your array? What is NewFlashcardVM.AddNewFlashcard?

Comment: NewFlashcardVM.AddNewFlashcard is ObservableRangeCollection (NewFlashcardVM is in ViewModel and there is ObservableRangeCollection ).

Comment: Add the reconnection method directly in your ViewModel, you can use something like ListAdd.ScrollTo(AddNewFlashcard[NewFlashcardVM.AddNewFlashcard.Count-1], ScrollToPosition.End, false);

Comment: Has the problem been resolved?

Comment: I tried today once again, and finally I find resolve :). I had to changed one method and call her in other place. Thank you so much :)